# Putty Help with @ Key

Tags: sftp, keys

I am new to putty.  I am pushing files to a customer with sftp command that includes @ sign in the command.  e.g. sftp (login@IP Address) the session will not allow @ on the command line.  It bounces me to the next line.  Can anyone tell me how to correct this.

Answer (score 1):

Your session eating @'s is very bizarre (what keyboard layout are you using?), but you can also use -o.

```
% sftp -o 'User foo' bar.com
```

or:

```
% sftp -o User=foo bar.com
```

is equivalent to

```
% sftp foo@bar.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Should probably be on super user, but just do

```
sftp <ip-address>
login: <login>
password: <password>
sftp>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a British keyboard with a machine set to a U.S. locale (or vice-versa) you might find that `"` and `@` are swapped.